# LineLegend displays as a PointLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

```
$Version
ListPlot[RandomReal[{1, 10}, {3, 10, 2}]
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}
 , PlotRange -> Automatic
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[
    {Red, Green, Blue}, {"R", "G", "B"}
   ]
   , After
   ]
 ]
```

Result on the free cloud account:

[image]

On its own, `LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"R", "G", "B"}]` works fine. This is also the case on v12.2.0 that I run locally. Am I using this incorrectly or is it a bug?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Using `ListLinePlot` restores the lines, but also draws the lines; so my guess is that it is inheriting some property from the type of the plot and formatting the legend accordingly. I would appreciate very much it if someone can share the correct explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so my guess is that it is inheriting some property from the type of
> the plot and formatting the legend accordingly.

**You can add the option `Joined -> True` in the following manner**

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{1, 10}, {3, 10, 2}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"R", "G", "B"}, 
    Joined -> True], After]]
```

This can be found under Option in [**`the docs for LineLegend`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html)

**Using [**`HoldForm`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html)**

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{1, 10}, {3, 10, 2}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[HoldForm@LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"R", "G", "B"}], 
   After]]
```

**Another approach is to use [**`Legended`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)**

```
Legended[ListPlot[RandomReal[{1, 10}, {3, 10, 2}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, PlotRange -> Automatic], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"R", "G", "B"}], After]]
```

> [image: plot]